# Setting variable attributes via subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to set an attribute ("full.name") of certain variables in a data frame by subsetting the dataframe and iterating over a character vector. I tried two solutions but neither works (varsToPrint is a character vector containing the variables, questionLabels is a character vector containing the labels of questions):

Sample data:

```
jtiPrint <- data.frame(question1 = seq(5), question2 = seq(5), question3=seq(5)) 
questionLabels <- c("question1Label", "question2Label") 
varsToPrint <- c("question1", "question2")
```

Solution 1:

```
attrApply <- function(var, label) {
  `<-`(attr(var, "full.name"), label)
}
mapply(attrApply, jtiPrint[varsToPrint], questionLabels)
```

Solution 2:

```
i <- 1
for (var in jtiPrint[varsToPrint]) {
  attr(var, "full.name") <- questionLabels[i]
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Desired output (for e.g. variable 1):

```
attr(jtiPrint$question1, "full.name")
[1] "question1Label"
```

The problems seems to be in solution 2 that R sets the attritbute to a new dataframe only containing one variable (the indexed variable). However, I don't understand why solution 1 does not work. Any ideas how to fix either of these two ways?

Comment: please add the sample dataframe with desired output to clarify your question

Comment: @ImranAli: Does that clarify what I meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1** :

The function is `'attr<-'` not `'<-'(attr...)`, also you need to set `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` (otherwise a matrix is returned instead of a list) and then call `as.data.frame` :

```
attrApply <- function(var, label) {
  `attr<-`(var, "full.name", label)
}
df <- as.data.frame(mapply(attrApply,jtiPrint[varsToPrint],questionLabels,SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

> str(df)
    'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ question1: atomic  1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "full.name")= chr "question1Label"
 $ question2: atomic  1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "full.name")= chr "question2Label"
```

**Solution 2** :

You need to set the attribute on the column of the data.frame, you're setting the attribute on copies of the columns :

```
for(i in 1:length(varsToPrint)){
  attr(jtiPrint[[i]],"full.name") <- questionLabels[i]
}

> str(jtiPrint)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ question1: atomic  1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "full.name")= chr "question1Label"
 $ question2: atomic  1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "full.name")= chr "question2Label"
 $ question3: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

Anyway, note that the two approaches lead to a different result. In fact the `mapply` solution returns a subset of the previous `data.frame` (so no column 3) while the second approach modifies the existing `jtiPrint` `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this perfect answer! That helped a lot!